# i18next translation outside component

Tags: json, i18next, react-i18next

I'm new for i18next, trying to localize/translate website. Everything works for translation inside of component, but outside (means json files with i18n.t() it doesn't retrieve needed information, instead showing default value.

I'm using create-react-app and it's default settings for folders reference, maybe this is the key problem, but I can't find out why and what to change.

```
import i18n from '../../i18n';


const navigation = [
    {
        'id'      : 'dashboard',
        'title'   : i18n.t('analytics.title', 'NOT FOUND'),
        'type'    : 'group',
        'icon'    : 'apps',

    }
  ]

export default navigation;
```

And here is settings for i18n.js file:

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import Backend from 'i18next-xhr-backend';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import detector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";

i18n

  .use(detector)
  .use(Backend)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    lng: localStorage.getItem('language') || 'en',
    backend: {
      /* translation file path */
      loadPath: '/assets/i18n/{{ns}}/{{lng}}.json'
    },
    fallbackLng: ['en', 'se', 'da'],
    debug: true,
    ns: ['translations'],
    defaultNS: 'translations',
    keySeparator: false,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
      formatSeparator: ','
    },
    react: {
      wait: true
    }

  })

  export default i18n;
```

and for index.js:

```
import 'typeface-muli';
import './react-table-defaults';
import './react-chartjs-2-defaults';
import { I18nextProvider } from "react-i18next";
import i18n from "./i18n";
import './styles/index.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import App from 'app/App';

 ReactDOM.render(
   <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
   <App />
   </ I18nextProvider>
   ,
   document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

I'm just getting default : 'NOT FOUND'...

Comment: Why do you have languages and namespaces swapped? `loadPath: '/assets/i18n/{{ns}}/{{lng}}.json'`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are using a backend service to fetch translations asynchronously in the browser. When importing `i18n` you probably expected translation to be readily available, but that's not the case - `i18n.init` is also an async method (if you try and await it, you'll be able to leverage `t` function).

One possible approach would be defining a translation key:

```js
const navigation = [
  {
    ...
    'title_key': 'analytics.title',
    ...
  }
]
```

And later passing it down to `t` within a component:

```
navigation.map(({ title_key }) => <li>t(title_key)</li>)
```

Comment: Thanks! Really elegant and smart idea!

Answer (score 1):

Can only echo what Pavel said. This saves me so much time!
Have gone through so many codes such as https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/issues/1236#issuecomment-762039023
But didnt work.

Only Pavel's suggestion works!
This allow you to still use useTranslation() in components while at the same time importing options from non-components (such as redux store/ )

For example I have something like this at Redux store/ folder:

```
export const xOptions = [
  {
    value: 'university',
    label: 'service_types_uni',
    imgPath: '/university.jpeg',
  },
];
```

And import it at components:

```
import xOptions from '../store/options/manyOptions'
import Card from '../components/Card';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
......
const ServicePage = (props) => {
 const { t } = useTranslation();
 return(

   xOptions.map((option) => (
     <Card title={t(`${option.label}`)} />
    )
   )
 )
```

}

Hope this helps someone too!