# react import translated strings from external file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, i18next

I import an object that i have on a constant file in my functional component, but it doesn't get translated according to the selected language.

I guess it's cause of timing, probably the language hasn't been loaded yet.

I cannot change the labels into string for several reason, so i need to understand how to update the i18n according to the language change.

so which is the best way to handle this?

is there a way to wait till the languages is loaded?

```
export const myTypes: FormSelectOptions = [
  { value: 'alpha', label: i18next.t('alpha.string') },
  { value: 'beta', label: i18next.t('beta.string') },
];
```

my i18n config

````
import Backend from 'i18next-xhr-backend';
import i18next from 'i18next';

i18next
  .use(Backend)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    backend: {
      loadPath: './translations/{{lng}}.json',
      addPath: './translations/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.missing.json',
      crossDomain: true,
    },
    resources: {
      en: {
        main: require('./translations/en.json'), // eslint-disable-line
      },
      it: {
        main: require('./translations/it.json'), // eslint-disable-line
      },
    },
    lng: 'it',
    defaultNS: 'main',
    saveMissing: false,
    saveMissingTo: 'all',
    fallbackNS: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? false : 'main',
    fallbackLng: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? false : 'en',
    debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
  });

export default i18next;
```
````

Comment: `myTypes` is defined inside of the component? Please provide your i18n configuration.

Comment: no it's defined outside in a different file and it's imported in the component

Comment: Does this answer your question? [i18next translation outside component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57114733/i18next-translation-outside-component)

Comment: the problem seems the same but the solution wouldn't work in my case

Comment: Add reproducible codesandbox or repository link to the description, so we can debug the problem.

Comment: You may want to check out the official react-i18next example: https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/tree/master/example/react